# What is reference stealing and borrowing ?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

While reading the documentation for the python C/API there are terms referring to reference stealing and borrowing. What do they mean ?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html - under Reference Counting / Details. It's pretty clear, IMOHO and my "answer" would merely be an excerpt of such documentation. Is there a *specific* question about such terms?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is See available in the Python documentation under: docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html - under Reference Counting / Details

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As user2864740 commented, those terms are defined in the [Reference Count Details section](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html#reference-count-details) of the "Introduction" page for the Python C API docs. Here are the relevant paragraphs:

> The reference count behavior of functions in the Python/C API is best explained in terms of ownership of references. Ownership pertains to references, never to objects (objects are not owned: they are always shared). “Owning a reference” means being responsible for calling Py_DECREF on it when the reference is no longer needed. Ownership can also be transferred, meaning that the code that receives ownership of the reference then becomes responsible for eventually decref’ing it by calling Py_DECREF() or Py_XDECREF() when it’s no longer needed—or passing on this responsibility (usually to its caller). When a function passes ownership of a reference on to its caller, the caller is said to receive a new reference. When no ownership is transferred, the caller is said to borrow the reference. Nothing needs to be done for a borrowed reference.
>
> Conversely, when a calling function passes in a reference to an object, there are two possibilities: the function steals a reference to the object, or it does not. Stealing a reference means that when you pass a reference to a function, that function assumes that it now owns that reference, and you are not responsible for it any longer.

Comment: So when passing a reference to a function, it is either a "stealing" or "borrowing"? What if the calling function increases the ref counter, what is it called in this case?

Comment: Increasing the reference count turns a borrowed reference into a reference you own yourself. Lots of code will do that. If you stole the reference passed to you by your caller, there is only rarely the need to increment the reference count, since you already own the reference you have. Doing so would mean you own *two* references to the object. That's only really useful just before you give one of the references away, by passing it to *some other* function that steals the reference from you.

Comment: Thanks, so it can happen as a subsequent action in either case. From a borrowed reference, increasing the ref_cnt makes the manipulation safe, and is a common practice. And from a stolen reference, it is rare to increase ref_cnt but still used in some cases. @Blckknght